# Matching multiple strings in regex_search or regex_findall gives other strings which should not match

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

Although I have checked previous similar questions, none seems to apply/work for me.
We're on Ansible version 2.9 as long as the rest of our infra will not be updated.
I have this list underneath which I need to filter on two strings.

```yaml
kvm_list:
  - abcdefabcfgh.domain.example
  - deffghabc.domain.example
  - abcblabla.domain.example
  - kabcxyz.domain.example
  - kesanu.domain.example
  - kesbapo.domain.example
  - kextoet.domain.example
  - kptfkom.domain.example
  - kgitblabla.domain.example
  - kgitblubblub.domain.example
```

```yaml
- name: "get them devtools"
  hosts: localhost
  ignore_errors: True
  tasks: 
    - set_fact:
         devtools: "{{ kvm_list | string | regex_search('kgit.*|kes.*', multiline=True)}}"
    
    - debug: var=devtools
```

When trying the above I get the underneath:

```
TASK [debug] **************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
"msg":"kesanu.domain.example','kesbapo.domain.example','kextoet.domain.example','kptfkom.domain.example','kgitblabla.domain.example','kgitblubblub.domain.example]"
}
```

`Kextoet` and `kptfkom` should not be included.

When testing this purely on regex ( https://regex101.com/ ) it works, when testing this in ansible it does not.

When using `regex_findall`, I get the same result.

When doing a regex search on one string it is correct.

If anybody could throw some hints or point to the obvious, I would be most grateful.

Comment: `kvm_list | string` is not doing what you think. You get a single line of text. The match returned starts at the first matching word and include the rest of chars exactly as you asked. You want to apply your regex on each list element, not on a cast of your list to a string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`select` filter](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.9.x/templates/#select) can achieve that:

```yaml
- set_fact:
    devtools: "{{ kvm_list | select('match','k(?:git|es)') }}"
```

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "devtools": [
        "kesanu.domain.example",
        "kesbapo.domain.example",
        "kgitblabla.domain.example",
        "kgitblubblub.domain.example"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Since `match` looks for expression at the beginning of the string, you can drop both `.*` in your above example => `'kgit|kes'`

Comment: @Zeitounator you're totally right. I'll edit the answer, thanks.

Comment: To respect the DRY principle, this could even be written as `'k(?:git|es)'`

Comment:  You should've posted your answer, it's the best one.

Comment: Thanks @Khaled and Zeitounator, just one question what does the "k" stand for in 'k(?:git|es)' ? I can not seem to find anything on the internet about this short form. I checked match and select doc. but no indication to what k stands for.

Comment: Thanks Khaled and @Zeitounator, just one question what does the "k" stand for in 'k(?:git|es)' ? I can not seem to find anything on the internet about this short form. I checked match and select doc. but no indication to what k stands for.

Comment: @trainin99 It's a part for the string you're trying to match`kgit` and `kes`. So `'k(?:git|es)'` means: match words start with `k` followed either by `git` or `es`

Comment: And to be exhaustive: `(?:<...>)` means "create a group with expression `<...>` but don't capture the result match" (i.e. non capturing group) since we don't have to reuse that anyway. If you ever need to capture, just drop the prepended `?:`